# C++ operator I/O overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've encountered a strange problem while overloading `<<` operator for a `Complex` class (The Complex class and overload function are not complete, but the meaning should be the same - BUT if you feel there is missing some important part, just prompt me ;-) ):

```
class Complex {
    float m_fReal;
    float m_fImaginary;
public:
    Complex();
    Complex(float real, float imaginary);
    Complex add(Complex) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< 
          (std::ostream& out, Complex cComplex);
};
```

Overload function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Complex cComplex) {
    out << cComplex.m_fReal << " " << cComplex.m_fImaginary;
    return out;
}
```

Add function:

```
Complex Complex::add(Complex cComplex) const {
    return Complex (m_fReal + cComplex.m_fReal,
                    m_fImaginary + cComplex.m_fImaginary);
}
```

Function call in main:

```
Complex x(1,1), y(2,2);
cout << "x+y=" << x.add(y) << endl;
```

While the above works, this does not (only parts that differ).

Declaration in `Complex` class:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< 
      (std::ostream& out, Complex& cComplex);
```

Definition:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Complex& cComplex) {
    out << cComplex.m_fReal << " " << cComplex.m_fImaginary;
    return out;
}
```

My intention was to pass the Complex class by reference. Can anybody explain to me, what went wrong in this code and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to accept the object to output by `const` reference. You're accepting it as a non-const reference to which the return from `add` cannot be bound.

`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Complex& cComplex) {`

This design/behavior is to prevent mistakes where a function expects to mutate the value of a reference parameter, but the reference has been bound to an unnamed temporary object, in other words memory that can't be accessed again, rendering the changes pointless.

Comment: Thank you, may I ask you why does it need to be that way? :)

Comment: I didn't realize that it is nonsense to pass it as non const :D Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Your definition should be

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Complex& cComplex) {
  out << cComplex.m_fReal << " " << cComplex.m_fImaginary;
  return out;
}
```

cComplex needs to be const qualified for you to access its private variables using "."